# Can I close my local terminal while ec2 server is training

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I am training a model on an ec2 server and the training has started. I connected to the ec2 server via ssh. Now the training will take quite a bit of time so during that time can I close my terminal or I should keep it open?

Comment: How did you start the 'training' process? Did you simply run a command from the SSH session? Did you run it in the background with `&`?

Comment: yes so after connecting to the ec2 server I ran a command python3 main.py --train

Comment: The best approach is to use `nohup`. See: [Keep processes running after SSH session disconnects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/488/130465)